# What happened to '…not about Apple hardware or software' as a Close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Question pretty much says it all - I was sure there used to be a close reason of 'not about Apple hardware or software'

Am I going completely barmy, or did it vanish in the recent rejig, same time as 'Basic Support' was added to the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can only have 4 close reason choices and we opted to drop that one in favour the new customer support reason. You can still use "Other..." I believe and enter the text there.

Comment: ah - didn't know there were only 4 possibles. Makes sense,... & yes, I just did type one in 'other' which was what prompted me to ask. Thanks.

Comment: Actually - if we had 5 reasons, the 5th ought to be "If you didn't have backup, tough!"

Comment: @Tetsujin If you wish to use the exact original text of the prior close reason in the custom field, it was `Questions about **non-Apple computing hardware and software** are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).` This custom close reason was deactivated on 2014-01-12.

Comment: Stack Overflow has 5 + belongs on another site + Other

Comment: Where is the meta question/discussion  on the new reason?

Comment: There was no meta discussion IIRC. It was a moderator-led decision.

Comment: @IanC.We only have 3 close reasons + Other - Other sites e.g. SuperUser have 4 + Other.. Did someone miscount or has the list changed?

Answer (score 2):

Also. Too broad or unclear often apply when someone asks what seems to be a PC or android question. Once you close it as unclear, it can quickly be deleted or edited if there is some relation to Apple products.